# My contact form sends emails from my dev server but throw 500 internal error after deploy on azure

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

#
I googled this for 3 days but could not find anything helpful. I am a student dev and I built my portfolio site with a contact form on the same page to receive emails. It all works fine on my dev server, but after deploying in on azure everything works except for the contact form. Please help. I will leave the link below if needed
#

### Here is the main controller that has the single page method(Index) and the method that sends the mail

```
using Salomon_Porfolio.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Portfolio.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Blog()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MailSender(ContactFormVm form)
        {

            try
            {


                var mailMessage = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com", "From my website") };
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@aol.com"));
                mailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com"));
                mailMessage.Body = form.Body;
                mailMessage.Subject = form.Name;

                var client = new SmtpClient();

                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                client.Send(mailMessage);




                return new EmptyResult();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.StackTrace);
            }


        }





    }
}
```

#### The script that post to the method through ajax

```
 var formData = $("#contactForm").serialize();
           $.ajax("/Home/MailSender", {
               method: "POST",
               data: formData,
               contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",


                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
           })
```

#### The configuration I add to my web.config file. The version of .Net is 4.6

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="mymail@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="mymail@gmail.com" 
                 password="mypassword"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

#### The contact form

```
  <form class="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <h3 class="formGroupClass">Contact me</h3>



            <div class="form-group formGroupClass">

                <label for="name">Name</label>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name,
                    new { @class = "formGroupClass form-control", placeholder = "John Smith" })


            </div>



            <div class="form-group formGroupClass">

                <label for="email">Email address</label>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "formGroupClass form-control" })


            </div>




            <div class="form-group formGroupClass">

                <label for="textarea">Your message</label>

                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body, 10, 55, new { @class = "formGroupClass form-control" })



            </div>



            <button class="btn btn-success" id="contactButton" type="submit">

                send
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
```

#### Error Message

```
          An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
       [Exception: something went wrong] 
    Salomon_Porfolio.Controllers.PageController.MailSender(ContactFormVm form) in C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SalomonPortolio_MVC Version\\Controllers\\PageController.cs:49\r\n   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104\r\n   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass10_0.&lt;WrapVoidAction&gt;b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14\r\n   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14\r\n   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +169\r\n
```

Comment: When you catch the exception and then throw a new one you're losing an important piece of information. What was the message of the original exception? That might tell you something important, but you don't have it. You're better off removing the try/catch altogether. The exception will already include the stack trace. By catching the exception and then rethrowing it that way you're just losing information.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I did not realise that. I will get rid of the try/catch and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @Scott! Again thank you for your help, you really relieved me from the nightmare i was going through. Now I see the error, and it is a common error that has been already solved:
Error message: `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.`